# By any chance, does anyone know what is the "yticks_pos" defined as?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand this code from this website "https://gist.github.com/mikkkee/f643acc70acc121a0171". However, when I tried to run this code, NameError: name'yticks_pos" is not defined was shown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO9eh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It must be a typo in the source code. Try substituting yticks_pos by yticks_locs

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I replaced it with yticks_locs. However, it displayed the next NameError: name 'yticks' is not defined.

Comment: Please try yticks_labels

Comment: Within the same function of plt.yticks (yticks_labels, yticks, fontproperties = plt_font)

However, I face the issue with yticks is not defined. I tried to replace it with yticks_locos, but it display a name_error _locos not defined.

Comment: Have you tried substituting yticks with yticks_labels? Anyway, I hate to say this, but, ... you do not seem to have debug many Jupyter notebooks. I think we both would stop wasting our time if you decided to solve your problems with sites as https://github.com/jupyter-resources instead of stackoverflow